# Curly Braces Inside a _.find Lodash Statement in an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I inherited a monster mess of an AngularJS project at my new job. I've been trying to resolve a bug recently that has the following Lodash statement:

```
 var group = _.find(groupList, {id: id});
```

From the documentation available on https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#find, which is the closest I can find to version 3.7.0, the _.find function iterates over a collection and returns the first object that the statement is "truthy" for. The second item inside the expression would represent a function to be executed.

However, I am confused about what the {id: id} is doing in this instance. Is this an Angular expression? What is it doing here exactly? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Searching for an object where the property `id` is the same as the `id` variable.

Comment: is the first id in the expression the property or the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means - search for an object in the array, that has the property `id`, with the value of the variable `id`.

```js
var groupList = [{ id: 21, name: 'cats' }, { id: 17, name: 'dogs' }, { id: 701, name: 'rats' }];

var id = 17;

var group = _.find(groupList, {id: id});

console.log(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So is the first id the variable or the property?

Comment: Nope, it's an object, for example `{ id: null }`, and the variable `id` is 2nd one `{ id: id }`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reading all the documentation in the link you posted? Specifically look at the Examples:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.result(_.find(users, function(chr) {
  return chr.age < 40;
}), 'user');
// => 'barney'

// using the `_.matches` callback shorthand
_.result(_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true }), 'user');
// => 'pebbles'

// using the `_.matchesProperty` callback shorthand
_.result(_.find(users, 'active', false), 'user');
// => 'fred'

// using the `_.property` callback shorthand
_.result(_.find(users, 'active'), 'user');
// => 'barney'
```

I believe the 2nd example that says

> // using the `_.matches` callback shorthand

answers your question.